# Testing Delayed Message With ActiveMQ and Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, activemq-classic

I have python code that puts several highly delayed (days to months) messages onto an ActiveMQ queue.  I would like to test if the code is correct by looking for those messages and making sure they are on the queue with the correct priority.  The problem is that the messages can't be popped off the queue until the AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY period has expired, and my unit tests can't run for month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the management tools to peek into the scheduler and see what is there.  There is a JMX Mbean in the newer releases of the Broker and there is also a way to do it via normal JMS Messages that request information be sent to the client.  I [wrote](http://timbish.blogspot.com/2010/10/enhanced-jms-scheduler-in-activemq.html) about this some time ago on my Blog.

The unit tests in ActiveMQ are always a good place to look for ideas on how to use and test various things dealing with broker features, there are tests for the [JMX Management](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/scheduler/JobSchedulerJmxManagementTests.java) and the [JMS Management](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/scheduler/JobSchedulerManagementTest.java) of the scheduler.